# Bootstrap 5 justify-content not working correctly and cannot vertically center content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following piece of code and I am use bootstrap 5:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br><br>

<div class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <h4>A Test Recipe</h4>
      <p>This is simply a test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-row align-self-center justify-content-end">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/15/19/09/food-1459693_1280.jpg"
           alt="A Test Recipe"
           style="max-height: 50px !important">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the image to the end of `list-group-item` div. I tried using `justify-content-end` but this has no effect. I also tried `align-self-end` this also doesn't bring the image to the right side.

And as for the div with the `flex-column` class I'm trying to vertically center its content. But it's not working either, it should be centered like the image is. I got the image vertically centered by making use of the `align-self-center` class. However when I apply this class to the div that has `flex-column` class it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

؟

```
<linkhref="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="card m-3 border-0" style="max-width: 250px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/15/19/09/food-1459693_1280.jpg"
                     class="img-fluid rounded-5"
                     alt="A Test Recipe">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">A Test Recipe </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is simply a test.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>

<div class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="card m-3 border-0" style="max-width: 350px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/15/19/09/food-1459693_1280.jpg"
                     class="img-fluid rounded-3"
                     alt="A Test Recipe">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">A Test Recipe </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is simply a test.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```